# How do I use dm-crypt (LUKS) with GnuPG to use two-factor for FDE?

Tags: encryption, luks, initramfs, gnupg

When using full disk encryption with Ubuntu (opposed to homedir encryption), dm-crypt with LUKS is used for encrypting the volume. In the installer (at least on 12.04 alternate) you can choose between setting it up using a passphrase *or* a keyfile. I'd like to use a combination of the two; not either, but require both.

Why? Because this enhances security (two-factor); you'll need to *have* something and you need to *know* something to unlock it. Then I want to put the keyfile on a small removable storage device (USB flash drive) and only plug it in during boot time. The result should be that it is required to put in the right flash drive *and* provide the right passphrase to unlock the root partition.

So, put in other words, I want to be asked during boot for the passphrase to which the keyfile on an external drive is encrypted.

I see a `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptgnupg` helper script that may help to accomplish it, but I have no clue how to use it.

<sub>Just to avoid confusion: I am *not* asking for a way to add an *additional* key to the volume to unlock it.</sub>

Comment: I've found one part of the answer myself by... *reading the docs*. Read up on how to use this in `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.gnupg`. I'll try to find some time on changing it to make it use a keyfile from external media.

Answer (score 5):

I do the same thing, however I'm afraid my answer won't be satisfactory, as for various reasons I went with a completely custom *Initramfs*.

Instead of `GnuPG`, which is an extra binary that has to be included in the *Initramfs* (and in case of `GnuPG-2`, a rather complex one), I simply used what's already there. And that's obviously `dm-crypt/LUKS`.

So suppose you have a `keyfile`. Preferably one with random data.

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=keyfile count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.000189802 s, 2.7 MB/s
```

Add encryption for it with LUKS (feel free to add your cipher settings of choice).

```
# truncate -s 2M keyfile.luks
# cryptsetup luksFormat keyfile --header keyfile.luks

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on keyfile.luks irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase: bananas
Verify passphrase: bananas
```

Now you have a keyfile (512 byte) and a keyfile.luks (2MB, which cryptsetup for some reason needs to write the 192k LUKS header). Since the Initramfs will be compressed anyway, that is not too bad (still smaller than `GnuPG`).

Now you can decrypt the keyfile:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen keyfile --header keyfile.luks lukskey
Enter passphrase for keyfile: bananas
```

And you have 512 byte of random data in `/dev/mapper/lukskey`. (You may write to it if you want to change it, so we could have initialized the file with zeroes earlier.)

```
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/lukskey
512
```

In *Initramfs* `init` you could then proceed to open the real LUKS volume with it (assuming you added the key first).

```
cryptsetup --key-file=/dev/mapper/lukskey luksOpen /dev/yourdisk luksyourdisk
cryptsetup luksClose lukskey # clean up
```

This approach makes GnuPG entirely superfluous, plus you get all LUKS advantages, such as multiple passphrases for the key, cipher of your choice, et cetera. Not to mention a nice (mostly regular) password prompt with multiple retries.

Comment: Cool solution, but how do I integrate this in my initramfs exactly?  You state that you use a completely custom initramfs, but wouldn't this be possible just by using a hook?

Comment: Certainly. Maybe even without a hook if you can think of a way to coerce crypttab to find and open the key somehow first. E.g. it does not have to be a file, you could make a separate partition for it on the USB stick. However since I'm not doing that way I can't make a concrete answer for it... sorry :-/

Comment: No problem at all - circumventing GnuPG and reusing LUKS is certainly a superior option. In case I need to rewrite hooks for the GnuPG approach, I'd better rewrite it without using it at all anyway. And yes, I am aware this does not have to be a file.

Comment: @gertvdijk if you get this going, I'd be interested in your answer for future reference